# Pyspark/jupyter notebook display issue with database

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I try to use PySpark with jupyter notebook. But when I want to see (a part of) the dataframe,
[image: it's not clean]...(some columns are even not shown).

I would like to have a display
[image: like this].
Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataframe is semicolon separated.
Pass that as a separator

```
df = spark.read.csv(path,sep=';')
```